# Python POST request 400 Bad requst

Tags: python

I am trying to send POST data to the url but I am getting 400 Bad Request. Whats the problem here?

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://tupodomen.info/api/login", data={'username': 
'<login>', 'password': '<password>'}, headers={'content-type': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(' <<<< ')
k=input("press close to exit")
```

Comment: The requests method call looks ok - 400 bad request usually implies a problem with the data structure or content. Are you sure the api expects that content-type? Can you provide a link to API documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible to answer this question without documentation on the endpoint that you're calling.  A 400 normally means there is something wrong with the format of the request.  One possibility would be that you're trying to send a Python dictionary when it should probably be stringified JSON, or you should use the `json` parameter instead.

Using `json` parameter:

```
r = requests.post("http://tupodomen.info/api/login", json={'username': 
'<login>', 'password': '<password>'}, headers={'content-type': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Stringified data:

```
r = requests.post("http://tupodomen.info/api/login", data=json.dumps({'username': 
'<login>', 'password': '<password>'}), headers={'content-type': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Comment: Then why this line works? req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

Comment: That's a different command, with different headers an no data... It's using the built in Python `urllib.request` to send the request.  Your posted question uses the third-party `request` library.  There's no reason to expect them to encode the data the same way by default.  Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I think you're correct but my code still goes 400 bad request: import requests
import simplejson as json

r = requests.post("http://tupodomen.info/api/login", data=json.dumps({'username': '<login>', 'password': '<password>'}), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}) 
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(' <<<< ')
k=input("press close to exit")

Comment: If I were trying to solve this problem, I might try using an alternate method of calling the endpoint, EG cURL or Postman.  Unforunately without documentation, you're left to guess why the request is failing.  If you can make a successful request using another method, maybe that will give you another clue to why you're getting the 400.